# Как сохранить значение вводимого в интерфейсе в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, сокет

Есть клиент-сервер приложение, пытаюсь прикрутить к нему графику: в менюшке пользователь вводи 2 числа и операнд, в 4ое окошко вылазит результат.
Как записать вводимые числа в переменные чтобы их потом я мог отправить на сервер, и как записать полученуню от сервера переменную с результатом, чтобы воткнуть ее в "окошечко" для результата?

```
import socket
import pickle
class Ops: #СЕРВЕР
    a = None
    b = None
    op = None

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 9090)
print('  {} порт таков: {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)

while True:

    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print('подключение от', client_address)

        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            # print('получили {!r}'.format(data))
            ops = pickle.loads(data)
            print(ops.a, ops.b, ops.op)
            if data:
                print('отправляю Клиенту')
                expression = ops.a + ops.op + ops.b
                print(expression)
                result = eval(expression)
                connection.sendall(str(result).encode())
            else:
                print('пусто', client_address)
                break

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

## клиент

```
import pickle
import socket


class Ops:
    a = None
    b = None
    op = None


sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
while 1:
    ops = Ops()
    ops.a = input("a= ")
    ops.b = input("b= ")
    ops.op = input("действие +; -; /; *  ")

    message = pickle.dumps(ops)
    sock.send(message)

    data = sock.recv(1024)
    res = data.decode()
    print(res)

sock.close()
```

===

## ГРАФИКА

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.sb_num1 = QSpinBox()
        self.sb_num2 = QSpinBox()

        self.cb_op = QComboBox()
        self.cb_op.addItems(['+', '-', '/', '*'])

        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        layout.addRow('num1', self.sb_num1)
        layout.addRow('num2', self.sb_num2)
        layout.addRow('op', self.cb_op)
        be=2 #<==вот даже такое число вставлять не хочет,не говоря о результатах
        self.result = QLineEdit('X___X',self) #X__X почемуто пишет и даже стирать можно, число же вставлять не хочет
        self.result.move(150, 88)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('broken garbage')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Window()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: А что вы хотите с WIndow делать?

Comment: В этом окошке вбить 2 числа и знак действия, затем их как-то отправить (код для клиент-сервер консольного сделал как в pyqt это воткнуть еще не понял) и потом получить в Window в 4ю полосочку результат записаный

Comment: 1) на окошко добавьте кнопку Отправить и QLabel для вывода результата
2) в функции, которая будет вызвана при клике на кнопку повторите код клиента сокета, который внутри цикла 3) результат res показывайте в том QLabel . Это самая простая реалиазация, есть и другая, но там работа с сервером-сокетом через поток делается и это сложнее для понимания и вообще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось немного подправить сервер:

```
import socket
import pickle

class Ops: #СЕРВЕР
    a = None
    b = None
    op = None

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 9090)
print('  {} порт таков: {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)

while True:
    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print('подключение от', client_address)

        data = connection.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            print('пусто', client_address)
            continue

        # print('получили {!r}'.format(data))
        ops = pickle.loads(data)
        print(ops.a, ops.b, ops.op)

        print('отправляю Клиенту')
        expression = ops.a + ops.op + ops.b
        print(expression)
        result = eval(expression)
        connection.sendall(str(result).encode())

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Интерфейс:

```
import pickle
import socket
import sys

from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ops:
    a = None
    b = None
    op = None


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('broken garbage')

        self.sb_num1 = QSpinBox()
        self.sb_num2 = QSpinBox()

        self.cb_op = QComboBox()
        self.cb_op.addItems(['+', '-', '/', '*'])

        self.button_send = QPushButton('Send')
        self.button_send.clicked.connect(self._on_send)

        self.result = QLineEdit()

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow('num1', self.sb_num1)
        layout.addRow('num2', self.sb_num2)
        layout.addRow('op', self.cb_op)
        layout.addRow('Result', self.result)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(layout)
        main_layout.addSpacing(10)

        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_send)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _on_send(self):
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

        ops = Ops()
        ops.a = str(self.sb_num1.value())
        ops.b = str(self.sb_num2.value())
        ops.op = self.cb_op.currentText()

        message = pickle.dumps(ops)
        sock.send(message)

        data = sock.recv(1024)
        res = data.decode()
        print(res)

        sock.close()

        self.result.setText(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Window()
    mw.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарствую - буду разбирать :) А то читая про сигналы чувствую как глаза разъезжаются :/